# Draw vertical HoughLines till certain intersection points

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

My idea is to draw all vertical lines, which are created by calculating the Canny before, from a intersection point to a diagonal lines to another intersection point (also this point comes from a intersection between a vetical and diagonal line). As a reference here an image, the red vertical (Hough)lines should be drawen: 
[image]

Until yet I just detect all vertical lines with this implementation:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<cv::Point> diagonalLine = DiagonalLines::diagonalLines(src);

  Mat wdst, cwdst, contRegion;
  vector<Vec4i> vericalLines;
  double maxLineGap = 200.0;
  double threshold = 100;

  std::vector<cv::Vec4i> elemLinesCur;                                              

  cv::Scalar mu, sigma;
  meanStdDev(src, mu, sigma);

  Canny(src, wdst, mu.val[0] - sigma.val[0], mu.val[0] + sigma.val[0], 3, false);
  cvtColor(wdst, cwdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

  HoughLinesP(wdst, vericalLines, 1, CV_PI / 2, threshold, 50, 200);

  cv::Vec4i current, previous;
  cv::Point pt1, pt2, ppt1, ppt2;

  for (size_t i = 1; i < vericalLines.size(); i++) {
    current = vericalLines[i];
    pt1 = cv::Point(current[0], current[1]);
    pt2 = cv::Point(current[2], current[3]);

    previous = vericalLines[i - 1];
    ppt1 = cv::Point(previous[0], previous[1]);
    ppt2 = cv::Point(previous[2], previous[3]);

    if (diagonalLine[i - 1].y > pt2.y && diagonalLine[i].y < pt1.y) {
        std::cout << "Intersection: " << pt2.x << "\n";
    }

    double distanceBetweenPointsX = abs(pt1.x - ppt1.x)*sqrt(2);

    if (distanceBetweenPointsX >= 12) {
        elemLinesCur.push_back(current);

        double angle = atan2(ppt2.y - ppt1.y, ppt2.x - ppt1.x) * 180.0 / CV_PI;     ///draw only vertical lines (90 degree)
        if (angle) {
            line(cwdst, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, CV_AA);
        }
//do some stuff
}
```

...and here a method, which detect only diagonal lines (it looks similiar to the above one):

```
std::vector<cv::Point> diagonalLines(cv::Mat src) {
std::vector<cv::Point> hitPoint;

Scalar mu, sigma;
meanStdDev(src, mu, sigma);

Canny(src, ddst, mu.val[0] - sigma.val[0], mu.val[0] + sigma.val[0], 3, false);

cvtColor(ddst, cddst, CV_GRAY2BGR);
HoughLinesP(ddst, vertlines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 100, 50, 10);

cv::Point pt1, pt2;
for (size_t i = 1; i < vertlines.size(); i++) {
    cv::Vec4i current = vertlines[i];
    pt1 = cv::Point(current[0], current[1]);
    pt2 = cv::Point(current[2], current[3]);

    double angle = atan2(pt2.y - pt1.y, pt2.x - pt1.x) * 180.0 / CV_PI;
    if (angle != -90 && angle != 90) {
        //line(cddst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, CV_AA);
        hitPoint.push_back(pt1);
        hitPoint.push_back(pt2);
    }
}
return hitPoint;
}
```

**What I know:**
I should calculate all those intersection points, yes, I also tried it in `if (diagonalLine[i - 1].y > pt2.y && diagonalLine[i].y < pt1.y)` but I don't get the further steps. Could some one help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV function `line()` accepts endpoints as the arguments, so all you need to do is calculate the intersections and use those intersection points for the endpoints of the vertical lines. You can calculate the intersection directly from the endpoints you have as the result of `HoughLinesP()` [using determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line).

In Python, a function to compute the intersection points might look like

```
def find_intersection(line1, line2):
    # extract points
    x1, y1 = line1[0]
    x2, y2 = line1[1]
    x3, y3 = line2[0]
    x4, y4 = line2[1]
    # compute determinant
    Px = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(x3-x4) - (x1-x2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / 
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    Py = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4)) /
        ((x1-x2)*(y3-y4) - (y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
    return (int(Px), int(Py))
```

Let's show how you might use this. Suppose your image looked like this:

```
# draw image and lines
img = np.ones((500, 500, 3)) * 255
diag1 = [(0, 0), (499, 100)]
diag2 = [(0, 499), (499, 399)]
vert1 = [(100, 0), (100, 499)]
vert2 = [(400, 0), (400, 499)]
cv2.line(img, diag1[0], diag1[1], color=[0, 0, 255])
cv2.line(img, diag2[0], diag2[1], color=[0, 0, 255])
cv2.line(img, vert1[0], vert1[1], color=[0, 255, 0])
cv2.line(img, vert2[0], vert2[1], color=[0, 255, 0])
```

[image: Full lines drawn]

To cut them off at the intersection, simply use the function to find those points and only draw the vertical lines at the intersection points with each diagonal line.

```
# get intersection points
vert1_intersect = [find_intersection(diag1, vert1), find_intersection(diag2, vert1)]
vert2_intersect = [find_intersection(diag1, vert2), find_intersection(diag2, vert2)]

# draw vertical lines from intersection points
img = np.ones((500, 500, 3)) * 255
diag1 = [(0, 0), (499, 100)]
diag2 = [(0, 499), (499, 399)]
vert1 = [(100, 0), (100, 499)]
vert2 = [(400, 0), (400, 499)]
cv2.line(img, diag1[0], diag1[1], color=[0, 0, 255])
cv2.line(img, diag2[0], diag2[1], color=[0, 0, 255])
cv2.line(img, vert1_intersect[0], vert1_intersect[1], color=[0, 255, 0])
cv2.line(img, vert2_intersect[0], vert2_intersect[1], color=[0, 255, 0])
```

[image: Vertical lines stopping at intersection point]

Comment: `line1` and `line2` should be 2x4 Points, right? Because I'm actually working with C++ and now I'm trying to implement your approach..

Comment: I'm failing in the third part `get intersection points` in my C++ code. :/ because my method `std::vector<cv::Point> diagonalLines` returns a vector

Comment: @Viktoria That's okay, you can just take any two points on the line! I would probably just take the first and the last point in the vector as the "endpoints" of the diagonal line. The formula works for any points on the line though, they don't have to be endpoints. In my code, maybe just ignore how I store each line. You can store them in the normal C++ vector of points format if you like. As you can see in the function, the important part is just to work with two pairs of points from each line. Pair 1 can be `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` and Pair 2 can be `(x3, y3), (x4, y4)`.